# OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd) not getting parameters from Oracle 18c StoredProcedure in .net framework 4.7.2

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, .net-4.7.2, oracle18c

The OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd) is not getting parameter values from Oracle 18c stored procedure.

I have upgraded my .net web application with framework version 3.5 and using Oracle 11g database to .net framework version 4.7.2 and Oracle database 18c.

The OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd) is not able to get parameter values from Oracle 18c stored procedure. Even though the stored procedure having 2 input and 1 output parameters .The method OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd) is returning zero.

All the privileges are provided at database end and the stored procedure is valid.

Comment: Did you do a clean build?  Are you using an ODBC connection?  Did you update the driver being used in the ODBC connection from Oracle 11g to Oracle 18c?

Comment: I have done the clean build and updated the connection string from Oracle 11g to Oracle 18c. Could you please let me know what are the other drivers I need to upadate. Thanks

Comment: Usually Oracle uses a ODBC connection and the ODBC name is in Control Panel : Administrative Tools : ODBC Data Sources.